# Upload an App to the App Store fails with cocoapod bundle identifier

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, cocoapods

I'm trying to upload an app to the App Store, everything runs fine until the upload that fails with this error

[image]

I'm sure that my bundle id is correct, since the error is with a pod bundle indentifier, I don't know where to change this

Comment: place Screenshot of Xcode where you have passed bundle ID